# Launch a fake/minimal X session for Pulseaudio/dbus

Tags: x11, pulseaudio

I use Pulseaudio to share audio between a desktop and a Raspberry Pi.

However, Pulseaudio needs dbus, and dbus needs an X session. Without graphical session, Pulseaudio is only able to run in system mode, which is officially not recommanded.

Besides on a Raspberry Pi, the cost of an X session is dramatically high, so I would like to get rid of it in the most efficient (less costly) way.

How can I start the smallest X session for Pulseaudio to kick in ?

Comment: Udev most definitely doesn't need X. I don't know about Pulseaudio: what fails in the absence of X? Is this related to D-Bus?

Comment: Well I've read that but it might be only Pulseaudio. In the absence of X Pulseaudio is launched in system wide mode, which means no per-user session, which is bad as the official website says : http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/WhatIsWrongWithSystemWide/

Comment: Sorry I mixed udev and dbus, edited.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [Xvfb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb), which is X server with a virtual framebuffer, i.e. an X server that displays only in memory and doesn't connect to any hardware. You don't need to run any client you don't want on that server, and in particular no desktop environment or window manager.

```
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1x1x8 &
```

After this:

```
DISPLAY=:1 dbus-launch
DISPLAY=:1 pulseaudio --start
```

You need to wait a little after starting `Xvfb` for the display to be available. You can use `xinit` to start an X server and then start clients when it's ready. Put the commands you want to run in a script (note that when the script exits, the X server exits):

```
#!/bin/sh
dbus-launch
pulseaudio --start
sleep 99999999
```

Start the virtual X server with

```
xinit /path/to/client.script -- /usr/bin/Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1x1x8
```

If you want to run it at boot time, you can start it from cron. Run `crontab -e` (as your user, not as root) and add the line

```
@reboot xinit /path/to/client.script -- Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1x1x8
```

If you want to kill this session, kill the `xinit` process.

Comment: Sorry to bother I struggle to automatically execute the pulseaudio start command (4th line of your example) at boot. I wonder if it is the DISPLAY property. I tried rc.local, /etc/init.d, rcS, but the script never starts pulseaudio. When I run my script via SSH it works perfectly. I would be glad if you could advice.

Comment: Xvfb has to do some setup before it is ready to accept X connections, so if the later commands run too soon, you may find they fail to connect to the X server.   You may want to look into using xinit to start Xvfb, and put those commands in the .xinitrc so that xinit starts them only once Xvfb is ready for them.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get you well. Do I have to start Xvfb with .xinitrc ? Right now it is started with rc.local. If so where do I put the PA command ? I tried starting PA command in .xinitrc but no luck, I'm missing something.

Comment: @kursus You need to run all these commands as your user. You can do it from a crontab with `@reboot`. Also alanc is right, there needs to be a delay after starting Xvfb, and xinit solves this issue. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, it's more clear now. However I get a _Unrecognized option: Xvfb_ when launching the xinit command, with or without the script call.

Comment: @kursus It seems that xinit requires the absolute path of the X server. Its command line parsing is a bit quirky.

Comment: That was it thank you ! I'm afraid of being hated but the cron command does not work : no X and no Pulseaudio. Here is what it looks like : http://imgur.com/KdiyaqO If I strip the absolute path for Xvfb, nothing happens at all.

Comment: I am trying to use this method to start a pulseaudio at :1 temporarily as an alternative to have it working for both :0 and :1, at [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/589448/wine-no-sound-at-x-1). But failed to play any sound thru pulseaudio, any idea?

Comment: How about using `xvfb-run`? It's much easier to use as long it offers features you need.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue yesterday, using Pulse audio for raspberrypi 0 W with DBus in a headless environment create with yocto without x11 and no systemd, you need to run and export dbus before you run pulseaudio.

```
if test -z "$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS" ; then
     echo "Starting dbus" 
     export $(dbus-launch)
fi
```

In etc/pulse/client.conf, please enable  allow-autospawn-for-root = yes

Run `pulseaudio -v` to check if there's another problem in your config.
Don't use `--system` switch because it won't be correct.

```
pulseaudio -D --disallow-exit
```